# Updating a controller property to updating at different locations in the module.(angular js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

angular module:

controller: property=errMsg

directive 1:
     condition 1:
          errMsg = "constant1"
     condition 2:
          errMsg = "const2"
end directive1

directive 2:
     condition 1:
          errMsg = "constant1"
     condition 2:
          errMsg = "const2"
end directive2

End:

This is the high level structure.
errMsg is the property to be accessed in the view and that property need to be updated with different constant within each directive. I was tried to access controller property inside the directive. but failed.  Can someone help to overcome this problem.

Comment: Check this [post](http://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/) related to scope binding between directive and controller.

Comment: the issue isn't very clear, maybe add a jsfiddle

Comment: How are your directives declared?  You're not going to get any useful help unless you post your code.

Comment: All previous comment are right, you cannot be less clear than that. If you want to share data from differents controller, and use them into a directive, I think the easiest way is to create a service, but I can be wrong because of the small stuff you provide..

Comment: Thank you very much for the approaches guys. I went through the guidance provided by the Nico and able to use a service. Used function in the ng-change and call it from the controller to retrieve the service property which i needed. Updated that property by setter method in each directive was able to put different constant values which i needed. Thx Nico for your guidence.